# Java ATM arrays error

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a ATM that can make deposit, withdrawal and show balance, but my problem comes when I'm trying to make my 11th transaction (The size of my transaction records is 10).

Here is how the program should work:

```
Earlier transactions:

=====================

1 

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

=======================

Balance: 55   KR

Earlier transactions:

=====================

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

11

=======================

Balance: 65   KR
```

I have to use those methods and haven't fully translated the program to English.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bankomat 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Declarer variables
        int[] trans = new int[10];  
        int amount = 0;
        int balance = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int theChoice = 1;

        while(theChoice != 4)
        {
            theChoice= menu();
            switch(theChoice)
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("\nDu valde \"deposit\"");

                System.out.print("\nState the value you want to take in: ");
                sum = in.nextInt();

                if(sum == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print("\nYou have given are wrong value.\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    amount = (int) + sum;
                    makeTransactions(trans,amount);
                }   

                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("\nDu valde \"withdrawal\"");

                System.out.print("\nState the value you want to take in: ");
                sum = in.nextInt();

                if(sum == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print("\nDu har angett ett felaktigt belopp.\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    amount = (int) - sum;
                    makeTransactions(trans,amount);
                }   

                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("\nDu valde \"Balance\"");
                showTransactions(trans,balance);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("\nDu valde \"Quit\"");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * MENU
     * @return val  skickar tillbaka input värdet
     */
    public static int menu()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice = 0;

        // Den här delen kommer att skriva ut menu
        System.out.println("1. deposit");
        System.out.println("2. withdrawal");
        System.out.println("3. Balance");                   
        System.out.println("4. Quit");                                   
        System.out.print("Your choice: ");

        choice = in.nextInt();

        return choice;
    }

    /**
     *  This method will sum up all the ten latest transaction and show the balance 
     * @param trans   array that saves the latest transactions 
     * @param balance Int that sums up all the values
     */
    public static void showTransactions(int[] trans, int balance )
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Tidigare transaktioner: ");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++)
        {
            if(trans[i] == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("");
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.print(trans[i] + "\n");
                balance = balance + trans[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("Saldo: " + balance + "KR" + "\n" );
    }

    /**
     * This method saves the latest transaction
     * @param trans array that saves the latest transactions
     * @param amount int that saves the latest transaction
     */
    public static void makeTransactions(int[] trans, int amount)
    {
        int position = findNr(trans);
        if(position == -1)
        {
            moveTrans(trans);
        }
        else
        {
            trans[position] = amount;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This metod will look for a empty position 
     * @param trans array that saves the latest transactions
     * @return position 
     */
    private static int findNr(int[] trans) 
    {
        int position = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++)
        {
            if (trans[i] == 0)
            {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * This method will move the transaction 
     * @param trans array that saves the latest transactions
     */
    private static void moveTrans(int[] trans)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++)
        {
            trans[0] = trans[i + 1];
        }   
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at stackOverflow.Testing.Bankomat.moveTrans(Bankomat.java:171)
    at stackOverflow.Testing.Bankomat.makeTransactions(Bankomat.java:135)
    at stackOverflow.Testing.Bankomat.main(Bankomat.java:41)
```

Line 171:

```
private static void moveTrans(int[] trans)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++)
    {
        trans[0] = trans[i + 1]; // This is line 171
    }   
}
```

Comment: What's your error? Can you be a bit more specific? `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: So it's an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** inside `moveTrans()`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bankomat
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Declarer variables
        int[] trans = new int[10];
        int amount = 0;
        int balance = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int theChoice = 1;

        while(theChoice != 4)
        {
            theChoice = menu();
            switch(theChoice)
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("\nDu valde \"deposit\"");
                System.out.print("State the value you want to take in: ");
                sum = in.nextInt();

                if(sum == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print("\nYou have given are wrong value.\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    amount = (int) + sum;
                    makeTransactions(trans, amount);
                }   

                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("\nDu valde \"withdrawal\"");
                System.out.print("\nState the value you want to take in: ");
                sum = in.nextInt();

                if(sum == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print("\nDu har angett ett felaktigt belopp.\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    amount = (int) - sum;
                    makeTransactions(trans, amount);
                }   

                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("\nDu valde \"Balance\"");
                showTransactions(trans,balance);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("\nDu valde \"Quit\"");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * MENU
     * @return val  skickar tillbaka input värdet
     */
    public static int menu()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;

        // Den här delen kommer att skriva ut menu
        System.out.print("\n1. Deposit\t");
        System.out.print("2. Withdrawal\t");
        System.out.print("3. Balance\t");                   
        System.out.println("4. Quit");                                   
        System.out.print("Your choice: ");

        choice = in.nextInt();
        return choice;
    }

    /**
     *  This method will sum up all the ten latest transaction and show the balance 
     * @param trans   array that saves the latest transactions 
     * @param balance Int that sums up all the values
     */
    public static void showTransactions(int[] trans, int balance )
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Tidigare transaktioner: ");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++)
        {
            if(trans[i] == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("");
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.print(trans[i] + "\n");
                balance = balance + trans[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("Saldo: " + balance + "KR" + "\n" );
    }

    /**
     * This method saves the latest transaction
     * @param trans array that saves the latest transactions
     * @param amount int that saves the latest transaction
     */
    public static void makeTransactions(int[] trans, int amount)
    {
        int position = findNr(trans);
        if(position == -1)
        {
            moveTrans(trans);
            trans[trans.length - 1] = amount;
        }
        else
        {
            trans[position] = amount;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This metod will look for a empty position 
     * @param trans array that saves the latest transactions
     * @return position 
     */
    private static int findNr(int[] trans) 
    {
        int position = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++)
        {
            if (trans[i] == 0)
            {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * This method will move the transaction 
     * @param trans array that saves the latest transactions
     */
    private static void moveTrans(int[] trans)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < (trans.length - 1); i++)
        {
            trans[i] = trans[i + 1];
        }
    }
}
```

**Changes:**

- Updated **`moveTrans()`** with correct logic

  - `i < (trans.length - 1)` and `trans[i] = trans[i + 1];`
- Updated **`makeTrans()`** such that it inserts the transaction at the right position when the array is full

  - `trans[trans.length - 1] = amount;`

**Input/Output:**

```
1. Deposit  2. Withdrawal   3. Balance  4. Quit
Your choice: 1

Du valde "deposit"
State the value you want to take in: 10

1. Deposit  2. Withdrawal   3. Balance  4. Quit
Your choice: 1

Du valde "deposit"
State the value you want to take in: 20

1. Deposit  2. Withdrawal   3. Balance  4. Quit
Your choice: 1

Du valde "deposit"
State the value you want to take in: 30

1. Deposit  2. Withdrawal   3. Balance  4. Quit
Your choice: 3

Du valde "Balance"

Tidigare transaktioner: 
-------------------------------------------

10
20
30
-------------------------------------------

Saldo: 60KR


1. Deposit  2. Withdrawal   3. Balance  4. Quit
Your choice: 1

Du valde "deposit"
State the value you want to take in: 40

1. Deposit  2. Withdrawal   3. Balance  4. Quit
Your choice: 3

Du valde "Balance"

Tidigare transaktioner: 
-------------------------------------------

20
30
40
-------------------------------------------

Saldo: 90KR


1. Deposit  2. Withdrawal   3. Balance  4. Quit
Your choice: 4

Du valde "Quit"
```

Comment: i can't use other methods then those i have and the program must show ten transactions always.

Comment: @yahya Those methods are not working correctly, I have updated the logic inside those methods to achieve your desired outcome. The **number of transactions** is defined as a **CONSTANT** in my program, you just need to change the value of `TRANS_SIZE` to 10.

Comment: i'm not allow to use global variables and constants in my program so i can only write int[] trans = new int[10];

Comment: @yahya Well, just replace all occurances of TRANS_SIZE with the numeric value 10, and you will be fine?? Nvm, I will do that for you. Updated answer.